# Apache CXF as Client for restful API - No message body writer has been found for class

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jsp, rest

I'm using Apache CXF to consume one companies Restful API. I'm getting the following error.

Caused by: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: .No message body writer has been found for class : class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, ContentType : application/json.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://aboti.securemanaged.com/rest/user");
            client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"Id\":1,\"name\":\"Alice\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"}");
            System.out.println("Sending" + obj.toString());
            //Response responseData = client.post(obj);
            String responseData = client.post(obj, String.class);
            System.out.println("Engine one started: " + responseData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But when I do curl I"m getting a valid JSON Response as follows:

```
curl "https://aboti.securemanaged.com/rest/user" -X POST -d '{"Id":1,"name":"Alice","version":"1.0.0"}'

{"trackingId":1564,"statusCode":"registered","status":"1"}
```

I tried to add a default Provider in my dispatcher servlet as follows:
But am not sure how can I configure the WebClient instance to use this default provider.. or is that not the issue?

```
  <jaxrs:client id="serviceId" serviceClass="" address="https://aboti.securemanaged.com/rest/user">
      <jaxrs:providers>
          <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
              <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
          </bean>
      </jaxrs:providers>
  </jaxrs:client>
  <bean id="jacksonMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
  <bean id="jacksonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
```

and then when you create your WebClient add the providers list as second parameter:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://aboti.securemanaged.com/rest/user", providers);
```